# The selection of specific fields from an array of js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
client.query("select * from rooms where token = ?", [data.token], function(err, results, fields) {
 callback(results);
 console.log(results); 
});
```

This is a query that returns the result as an array. How can I get the necessary fields?

Comment: What does console.log(results) return? Have you tried results.field1, results.field2 etc?

Comment: console.log(results) return: [ { bump: 1376149484, user: 'alex', token: 11569, active: 0 } ]
results.field1, results.field2 return "null"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment, if the json object is -:

```
[
   {
      "bump":"1376149484",
      "user":"alex",
      "token":"11569",
      "active":0
   }
]
```

You can iterate through the object like so -:

```
for (var i in results)
{
  console.log('bump = ' + results[i].bump);
  console.log('user = ' + results[i].user);
  console.log('token = ' + results[i].token);
  console.log('active = ' + results[i].active);
}
```

Comment: If `i` is not already defined, I believe you will need `for(var i in results)`